# New user verification by Admin only

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, user

When a user signs up to my website I want to send that request to the Admin and after Admin verifies that user than only user should login to the website. Is there any way I can implement this feature in Magento 2 ?

I'm new to Magento So, apologize if I asked anything that I shouldn't.

Comment: You can use https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-customer-approval-extension.html OR https://marketplace.magento.com/mageplaza-module-customer-approval.html

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-customer-approval/ its a free plugin and he will do the job

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this with an observer on `layout_load_before`. Here with this code i wanted to prevent the access to a specific "pro store" but you can get rid on the store checking process and apply the condition everytime or in your case on the users that might not be activated yet or whatever you need to do.

```
class RedirectCustomer implements ObserverInterface{
/**
 * @var ResponseFactory
 */
protected $responseFactory;

/**
 * @var Session
 */
protected $_customerSession;

/**
 * @var Url
 */
protected $_customerUrl;

/**
 * @var UrlInterface
 */
protected $_urlInterface;

/**
 * @var Http
 */
protected $request;

/**
 * @var StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 */
protected $storeManager;

/**
 * RedirectCustomer constructor.
 * @param ResponseFactory $responseFactory
 * @param Session $customerSession
 * @param Url $customerUrl
 * @param UrlInterface $urlInterface
 * @param Http $request
 * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 */
public function __construct(
    ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
    Session $customerSession,
    Url $customerUrl,
    UrlInterface $urlInterface,
    Http $request,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_customerUrl = $customerUrl;
    $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}

/**
 * @param Observer $observer
 * @throws NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function execute(Observer $observer){
    $loginRedirectUrl = $this->getCustomerLoginUrl();
    $currentUrl = $this->_urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();
    $fullActionName = $this->request->getFullActionName();
    $currentStoreCode = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
    $isStorePro = $currentStoreCode == 'pro';

    if($isStorePro){
        if(!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()
            && $currentUrl != $loginRedirectUrl
            &&  $fullActionName != 'customer_account_forgotpassword'
            && $fullActionName != 'customer_account_createpassword'
            && $fullActionName != 'customer_account_create'
            && $fullActionName != 'customer_section_load') {
            $resultRedirect = $this->responseFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setRedirect($loginRedirectUrl)->sendResponse('200');
            exit();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getCustomerLoginUrl(){
    return $this->_customerUrl->getLoginUrl();
}
```